# C# Reverse PROXY (bypass NAT / FIREWALL)

Tags: c#, proxy, reverse, socks

right now Im searching for like 6h to get into it!
My brain is done!

Ok, heres the deal:

I'm searching a solution, to connect to a PC behind a Router wich is running the Proxy Server to passthrough my Information.

So like this:

Me (wanna connect to 1.1.1.1) --> Internet --> 1.1.1.1 -> Router --> PC With the running Server --> Internet

I've read aboud STUN / STUNT.. But I actually know the IP where the Server listen to some Port.

The problem is with UDPpunch hole is, that the proxy actually doesnt know the Clients IP.

Comment: Made a new question, because this one is confusing :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579566/makeing-a-proxy-connection-both-client-server-behint-nat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STUN requires a server accessible to both peers (usually that means a public IP address). The server negotiates both peer-discovery and the STUN handshake.

Comment: Ive tried it with the C# STUN sample. But how should it be possible to tell the STUN Server who I want to connact to!?
Can I use Public Stun Server?

Do You have a example code?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't entirely what the Azure Service Bus is for?

http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Azure/ServiceBus/

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/appfabric/

Comment: Sorry this one is a paid service